# Change TextView behaviour when in ScrollView

Tags: android, textview, scrollview

**Context :**
I have a scroll view with a linearLayout. In this linear layout i have several objects (LinearLayout).

**Problem :**
When i give focus to one of my objects the scrollView scroll to put the object in the center of the list.
BUT When i give focus to a textView (into one of my objects), scrollView scroll to put the textView collapse to keyboard.

**Question :**
Is it possible to stop the behaviour of the TextView in ScrollView to keep focus object in the middle of the list ?

thanks in advance for your answers !

Comment: I can change my objects container for now this is LinearLayout but i've tried with cardView with the same result